# How can I loop through a string two lines at a time (two carriage returns per iteration)?

Tags: string, vb.net, loops, split

I want to loop through a string two lines at a time. I know I can loop through each line in a string by splitting on carriage return with the following:

```
For Each line As String In Split(myString, vbCrLf)
 //do something with line
 Continue For
End If
```

How might I iterate through a string two lines at a time? Do I have to use two loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the loop you are after with a `For..Each` loop as the definition of that loop is to loop through each element.

You need to use an old-fashioned `For` loop with a counter and a `Step` instruction.

```
Dim stringArray As String() = Split(myString, vbCrLf)

For loopCounter As Integer = 0 To stringArray.Length - 2 Step 2
    If (loopCounter + 2 >= stringArray.Length) Then
        ' Need to handle the scenario for an Odd number of items in the array
        Debug.WriteLine($"{stringArray(loopCounter)}")
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine($"{stringArray(loopCounter)}:{stringArray(loopCounter + 1)}")
    End If
Next
```